# Changing a Table View Controller to a Collection View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a Table View Controller and I want to change it to a Collection View Controller, my app gets its information using JSON.

I already created a Collection View Controller in my Storyboard. My view Controller is called "UpcomingReleasesViewController" and I have a UICollectionViewCell called "UpcomingReleaseCell". In my Storyboard I have a label linked to the Collection Cell called "release_name".

I want to transfer the code that I had in my TVC but I'm having some trouble updating it.

The code I added to my UpcomingReleasesViewController.h (like I had in my TVC)

```
@interface UpcomingReleasesViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *upcomingReleases;

@end
```

I added this code to my UpcomingReleasesViewController.m (I get an error when I call **cell.textLabel.text**)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.upcomingReleases = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {
        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        [self.upcomingReleases addObject:upcomingRelease];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;

    return cell;
}
```

Also in when I was using the TVC I had a NSObject called "UpcomingRelease" with the following code:

**UpcomingRelease.h**

```
@interface UpcomingRelease : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *release_name;

// Designated Initializer
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)release_name;
+ (id) upcomingReleaseWithName:(NSString *)release_name;

@end
```

**UpcomingRelease.m**

```
@implementation UpcomingRelease

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)release_name {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ){
        self.release_name = release_name;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (id) upcomingReleaseWithName:(NSString *)release_name {
    return [[self alloc] initWithTitle:release_name];
}

@end
```

Should I create a NSObject for my new app and add that code or should I add it to my UpcomingReleaseCell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you register your custom cell?

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UpcomingReleaseCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"UpcomingReleaseCell"];
```

Comment: in viewDidLoad for example.

Comment: What else do I have to do? I get this error: Property 'release_name' not found on object of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to register the cell when using storyboard
2. Select the CollectionViewCell from storyboard and change the class to "UpcomingReleaseCell" in identity inspector by selecting the
3. Add the label in collectionviewcell and connect the cell to "UpcomingReleaseCell" with name "release_name"
4. Add the following in "cellForItemAtIndexPath"

   ```
   (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UpcomingReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // Configure the cell

   UpcomingRelease *upcomingrelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.release_name.text = upcomingrelease.release_name;

   return cell;
   }
   ```